# Please help me understand why the modulus works this way.

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I am very confused by the following equation:

$$ \mathbb {-1\%4=3}$$

I understand that the modulo or modulus operator gives the remainder of a division. This is not new or a mystery to me. What I am confused about is how the remainder is the integer 3. This does not make logical sense to me.

For instance, if I do -1 / 4 I get -0.25 shown in the following equation:  $\mathbb {-1 / 4 = -0.25} $ Where is the 3 in the remainder?

Or check this out, if I calculate the modulus of another couple of numbers the answer is much simpler for me to understand. Check this out:  $$\mathbb {5 \% 3 = 2} $$

This is obvious that the remainder is 2 because $\mathbb {5 / 3 = 1 R2}$  The R2 means remainder of 2. So, in other words 5 / 3 = 1 with a remainder of 2. This makes sense why the modulo is of 5 % 3 is 2 based on the result of the division.

**I am confused though why $\mathbb {-1 / 4 = -0.25}$ but $ \mathbb{-1 \% 4 = 3}$. Can you help me understand this?**

Thank-you for reading this.

Comment: You are supposed to do integer division.  $3=4\cdot1-1$  Or $-1=4(-1)+3$ if you like.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_division

Comment: Whoa, that is awesome. The first i have read about this. Could you please elaborate or link to a website that explains "integer division" in more detail?

Comment: A historical note: in the past, designers of computer languages also had some doubts about how to handle the modulus operator applied to negative numbers, and not all languages (or even all implementations of one language) gave the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a subtle difference between the usage of $=$ (equality) and $\equiv$ (equivalence).

We say $$a\equiv b\pmod c\implies a=b+cx, x\in\Bbb Z.$$

All integers will fall into one of four categories:  $0, 1, 2$, or $3\pmod 4$, depending on which one of these numbers you have to *add* to some multiple of $4$ you have to get your integer.  In your case, in order to get $-1$, you have to add $3$ to $-4$, and therefore, we have $-1\equiv 3\pmod 4$.

Comment: Interesting. Confusing. I was not wondering about the difference between equality and equivalence. I did come across some equivalence symbols when researching this problem last night however. I am not sure why though. When you write, "All integers will fall into one of four categories: 0, 1, 2, or 3" do you mean for this particular problem? Also, where did the -4 come from? The problem was -1 % 4 = 3 that is baffling. Sorry I am not really a mathematician. I am surprised how confusing this is. Do you know where I could read more about this?

Comment: The statement $$-1\equiv p \pmod 4$$ translates to "_Which non-negative integer $p$ below $4$ do you have to add to some multiple of $4$ in order to get $-1$?_"

Comment: I write "All integers will fall into one of four categories:  $0\pmod4$, $1\pmod4$, $2\pmod4$, or $3\pmod4$.  In general, if we are talking about equivalence cases $\pmod k$, then all numbers fall into one of those $k$ categories:  $0\pmod k$, $1\pmod k$, $\ldots$, $(k-1)\pmod k$.

Comment: @user_loser this branch of mathematics is called [modular arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic).

Answer (score 1):

The modulus operator $a\%b$ in your computer language will always produce a number between $0$ and $b-1$ (assuming $b > 0$). It looks at all the numbers
$$
\ldots, a-2b, a-b, a, a+b, a+2b, \ldots
$$
and returns the one between $0$ and $b-1$.

If $a > 0$ you can find that value with ordinary division with remainder. You should not be thinking about decimal fractions for $-1\%4$.

Comment: You write, "You should not be thinking about decimal fractions for -1 % 4". What should I be thinking about? ^_^ That is helpful to know about the the number always being 0 and b -1 if b is greater than zero for a%b. That is also very helpful to know about if a is greater than zero then I can use "ordinary division". :) I am confused about the part that "looks at all the numbers..." How does it find the answer? Is there more than one answer, is there a simple algorithm to find the answer? Thank-you for taking the time to answer Ethan! :)

Answer (score 1):

If $y = a x + b$ where $y, x, a, b$ are integers (with $x > 0$) and $0 \le b < x$, then we say $b$ is the remainder on dividing $y$ by $x$, denoted $y \% x$.

In this case you write $-1/4 = -.25$, but in this case it would be better to write it as $-1 + 3/4$.

Comment: Thank-you Robert for answering. Your answer is beyond my understanding. In other words this answer went over  my head because the mathematics is above my current understanding. I am not really a math person just an IT professional. :)

Comment: Your equation that you mention "y = ax + b" looks much like the geometry equation y = mx + b. ^_^ I am confused by your answer even more so, much like all the other answers given. You will have to forgive me as I am not a mathematics professional. Thank-you sir for the reply though. This makes me think, which is good.